# How to get information about from where parameters came like webstor shows

Tags: javascript, webstorm, visual-studio-code

I don´t know how to explain it exact. 
I saw in webstorm has something like this

```js
    set(nbObstacles, nbWeapons, nbPlayers){
        this.setTiles();
        this.setElements(type: "obstacle", nbObstacles);
        this.setElements(type: "gun", nbWeapons);
        setInterval(handler: () => {
            this.draw();
        }, timeOut: 1000 / 50)
```

**type:** 
**handler** and
**timeOut**

are information shown by webstorm. I would like to have the same on Visual studio code.

Someone knows if. 
Is there any plugin to could show the same like webstorm?

Comment: Please, submit working fiddles... that one doesn't work for me. We can edit, but it's better if you change it yourself. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don´t follow you. I am trying to translate working fiddles, but I am not sure the meaning of that sentence.

@user103963